# Is it possible to pick up DOM element inside of iFrame on click?

Tags: c#, .net, iframe, browser

I'm using `C# .NET Framework 2.0` to create application that can **pick up clicked part of DOM element by user in WebBrowser control.**

So far I can pick html tags and its attributes in the HTML in WebBrowser control.

```
//adding event when user mouse down or focus out
webBrowser1.Document.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(myMouseDown);
```

And those event would output DOM information to listbox etc

```
 private void myMouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
 {
    HtmlElement tag = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);

    txtRecord.Items.Add("TagName=" + tag.TagName);
    txtRecord.Items.Add("id=" + tag.GetAttribute("id"));
    txtRecord.Items.Add("name=" + tag.GetAttribute("name"));
    txtRecord.Items.Add("type=" + tag.GetAttribute("type"));
    txtRecord.Items.Add("value=" + tag.GetAttribute("value"));
    txtRecord.Items.Add("class=" + tag.GetAttribute("class"));
    txtRecord.Items.Add("inner text=" + tag.InnerText);

 }
```

But then the events mouseDown is not working in iFrame.

When I click inside of the iFrame, it does not spit DOM information.

Is it possible to pick up DOM info by user clicking on that spot in iFrame?

UPDATE:

Found HtmlWindow object and applied same event logic.

```
HtmlWindow iFrame;
iFrame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
iFrame.Document.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(myMouseDown);
```

But then the last line throws UnauthorizedAccessException :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why I'm getting **UnauthorizedAccessException**. It's because my main page is http://localhost/index.html while iFrame src is  which violates **cross-frame scripting security** according to:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171715.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028.aspx
```

I've changed iFrame src to use same domain, http://localhost/secondPage.html

then it start working!